# Замена повторяющегося действия в PHP

Tags: php

Есть 30 переменных, каждая из них хранит значения:

```
$level1 = 36;
$level2 = 72;
$level3 = 144;
$level4 = 288;
```

Есть сценарий, который смотрит на кол-во опыта(значение переменных), если опыт подходит, то отправляет в бд уровень. Сценарий:

```
if ($experience <= $level1) {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE $db_table SET level = 1 WHERE id ='$id'");
} else {
    if ($experience <= $level2) {
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE $db_table SET level = 1 WHERE id ='$id'");
    } else {
        if ($experience <= $level3) {
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE $db_table SET level = 2 WHERE id ='$id'");
        } else {
            if ($experience <= $level4) {
                $result = mysql_query("UPDATE $db_table SET level = 3 WHERE id ='$id'");
            } else {
                if ($experience <= $level5) {
                    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE $db_table SET level = 4 WHERE id ='$id'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как видно из сценария, каждое действие практически повторяется, код получается длинным, можно ли его сократить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В три строчки:

```
$levels = array( $level1, 72, 144, 288, ... , $level30, $experience);
sort( $levels);
$result = mysql_query( sprintf("UPDATE %s SET level=%d WHERE id='%s'",
    $db_table, 1 + array_search( $experience, $levels), $id));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$levels = array($level1, $level2, $level3, ..., $level30);
foreach($levels as $key=>$level)
{
    if ($experience <= $level)
    {
        $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE $db_table SET level = $key WHERE id =$id");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ..и у нас чудесным образом появляется нулевой уровень! : )

Answer (score 2):

Толи я извращенец, то ли все вокруг:

```
for($a=36,$i=1;(($experienced-$a)>=0);$a*=2,$i++); //<--- Внимание: точка с зпт
print ("Ваш уровень: $i\n");
print ("следующий ап на: $a\n");
print ("сейчас опыта: $experienced\n");
```

Надеюсь как это сшить с sql запросом сам придумаешь, не так это и сложно.

**UPD:**
Я извращенец:

```
for($a=36,$i=1;(($experienced-$a)>=0);$a*=2,$i++);
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE $db_table SET level = $i WHERE id ='$id'");
```

Уж хз какое быстродействие будет, но мозг я себе поломал.

Comment: классно с множественными стейтментами в `if()`! Забыл, что так можно. Спасибо.

Comment: да не за что. Я ща книгу по Си читаю. Там такие примеру сплошь и рядом.

Answer (score 0):

Заведите таблицу уровней. Уровень для каждого игрока хранить не стоит. Его в любой момент можно получить по опыту. Это избыточное хранение данных. Если у вас экспа уровней поменяется, придется апдейтить всю базу.

Вот вам пример структуры и запроса [на SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91a34/7).

Comment: Миллион игроков, при входе каждого нового, его следует отправить в "комнату" с перцами его же "уровня". Что быстрее: каждый раз считать, снова и снова, или сделать выборку по индексу?
Вопрос не «как жить правильно», а как конкретный php код оптимизировать. Вы бы ещё на Python перейти посоветовали )

Comment: Если вы обратите внимание на свой же ответ, то, чтобы получить быструю выборку по индексу, вам придется апдейтить каждого из миллиона игроков при каждом обновлении экспы. Вот и посчитайте сколько у вас будет апдейтов ежемиллисекундно ради одного запроса по индексу раз в полчаса.  
Вы бы еще игроков захардкодить посоветовали. =)

Comment: Как увлекательно обсуждать устройство чего-то там, с «бы», ага..
Ожидается ответ на поставленный вопрос, а не мыслью по древу.

Comment: @sergiks, правильно "мысью по древу". Ваша "оптимизация" ничем не лучше исходного листинга. Короче, да, но не оптимальнее. То, что вы отвечаете новичку в стиле "каков вопрос - таков ответ" врядли принесет пользу в конечном итоге. И судя по тому, что ответ ваш приняли, оптимизация только начинается.
Спасибо, кстати за минус, я их коллекционирую.