# Быстродействие. if vs цикл

Tags: производительность

После [этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129825/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-php?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=130074#130074) стало интересно.
Дано множество значений, подчинённых определённой прогрессии:

```
A = {x: x(i) < x(i+1) и x(i+1)=2*x(i)}
```

Надо сравнить их с входящими данными.
Что будет быстрее: цикл или N раз написать ifelse?

Такими вещами, как читабельность кода, можно пренебречь.
Аналогичных вещей в инете не нашёл, т.к. обычно сравнивают производительность однотипных операций.

P.s. вопрос больше теоретический, так что ЯП любой.

Comment: Если это прогрессия алгебраическая или геометрическая, то при больших N наверно производительнее вычислить i члена прогрессии для числа из входящего потока, но это субъективное мнение.

Comment: Я об этом думал. Но по сути интерес был в другом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 вариант - Цикл или условие разницы не будет, поскольку это все равно будет примерно одно и тоже количество сравнений и прыжков. Поскольку мы анроллим не вычисления а сравнения.

2 вариант - Условия будут работать медленней поскольку это займет больше кода, и получим пенальти из-за дополнительной загрузки из памяти и кеш миссов. (Эффект, конечно, будет на больших Н).

Вообще тут дело не только в языке и компиляторе, но и процессоре. Измеряйте и пробуйте, но в любом случае это микро оптимизации, до которых спускаться в продакшене не стоит.

Comment: В игроделе бывает на микрооптимизации выигрываются огромные ресурсы.

Answer (score 4):

Если учитывать время написания if'ов, то циклы реально быстрее.

Comment: Это пять с плюсом. =)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то современные компиляторы умеют оптимизировать код. Правда, они делают это не лучшим образом, но зачастую этого достаточно. Одним из стандартных приемов является разворачивание циклов в линейный код, потому что процессору удобнее выполнять код без ветвлений. Еще при оптимизации приходится учитывать особенности архитектуры процессоров, в частности - как они работают с ОЗУ.
И получается, что соптимизировав код под один из процессоров, вы можете получить совершенно неоптимальный код под другие. Ну, и к тому же есть разные критерии оптимизации. Основных два: по скорости выполнения кода и по размеру кода. Так что в компиляторы вводят ключи для точного задания под что и как Вы хотите оптимизировать.

Итак, в Вашем случае необходимо попробовать протестировать разные варианты программы и сделать вывод о том, что лучше, самостоятельно. Причем желательно проверить еще и с разными режимами компиляции.

Comment: " Правда, они делают это не лучшим образом" не совсем правда. Чаще всего, если компилятор что-то делает "не так" - виноват в этом программист

Answer (score 2):

[[@zenith](/users/5568/zenith)](/users/5568/zenith) - в этом случае, вы не оптимизируете код лучше компилятора.

Если код можно привести к линейному - он будет к нему приведен. Соответственно заниматься подобными размышлениями стоит только в том случае, если вы пишите на ASM

А в языках, где нет даже JIT компилятора это, как минимум, не увеличит производительность, как максимум - сделает еще хуже... ( и не забываем про 100500 if, else блоков )

Answer (score 1):

Это экономия на спичках. В веб-разработке не важно что работает быстрее: if или for, поскольку время ожидания ответа от БД несравнимо больше выигрыша в быстродействии от замены for на if или наоборот.

С другой стороны рекомендую прочитать про китайский код в статье [http://lurkmore.to/Индусский_код](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Answer (score 0):

> Такими вещами, как читабельность кода, можно пренебречь.

Это вы сейчас серьезно?! Пренебрегать читабельностью кода это как ходить по улице в рваной грязной одежде, Вы в такой одежде ходите? Я думаю, что нет. Тогда почему Вам наплевать на чистоту кода?

> Что будет быстрее: цикл или N раз написать ifelse?

А если вам нужно будет проверить 100 раз? Вы будете 100 раз писать if else?

Если вам так интересно узнать что быстрее, то проведите тесты на замер времени исполнения кода.

P.S. используйте цикл и не забивайте голову не нужной ерундой.

Comment: Я бы не стал упоминать, что вопрос теоретически если бы он не был таковым. Конечно с разумной точки зрения один цикл воспринимается лучше, чем 1лям ифов. Но вопрос ведь не в этом? И ваша полемика получается не в тему.

Comment: почитайте еще раз мой ответ....

Если вам так интересно узнать что быстрее, то проведите тесты на замер времени исполнения кода.

P.S. используйте цикл и не забивайте голову не нужной ерундой.

Comment: @Jetu - человек задал абсолютно нормальный вопрос. То, что вас не интересуют столь низкоуровневые вещи, не означает того, что вопрос ерунда.

"не нужной ерундой"? По вашей логике ASM тоже ненужная ерунда, но если бы его не было - был-бы вообще машинный код :)

Comment: посмотрите какие вопросы задавал человек, скажите мне как связан веб программист с ассемблером? и где вы тут увидели асм? человек спросил что быстрее циклом или условиями? я ему ответил, проведите тест на время исполнения, проводить за него эти тесты я не буду.
Такое ощущение, что никто не дочитывает ответ до конца......

Comment: "и где вы тут увидели асм?" да везде он. Даже когда вы JS пишите, в православных браузерах, самые "горячие" функции и т.д. компилируется в АSM ( в идеале линейный ).

Непосредственно ответа вы не дали.

К тому-же, скорее, это вы не дочитали вопрос.

цитирую: ***"P.s. вопрос больше теоретический"***. Вы же писали так, как-будто вы думали что ТС реально будет применять такой подход.

Comment: @jetu не переходите не личности. Если человек пишет на php на работе, то не стоит полагать, что он игнорирует C, Java и другие прелести жизни. И кстати, асёл тоже ждёт своего часа :)

Comment: личности? тыкнете меня лицом в то место где я кого нибудь оскорбил или унизил и я тут же извинюсь перед этим человеком.
непосредственного ответа я не дал? Окааай...... 
Давайте не будет разводить флуд, ответ уже дан, толку в нашем споре 0.

Comment: скажите мне как связан веб программист с ассемблером?  
Можете не извиняться, но звучит как "они с другой планеты".

Comment: ну может это Вы так прочитали, я имел ввиду совсем другое, веб программист не программирует же микроконтроллеры? нет. это же разные ветки программирования. Так же как и архитектор БД не пишет драйвера на чистом Си.

Comment: Закрыли и забыли. Моя накофеининая натура уже готова нежно воткнуть вилку в глаз коллеги за другие музыкальные пристрастия.